# string1.Equals(string2) in if statement - no such member as Equals and expression must be BOOLEAN

Tags: string, delphi, if-statement, equals

I am trying to make a if statement where I want to compare 2 strings, whether they are equal or not in condition.

This is what I have

```
 if  vysledok.Equals(meno) then
 Application.MessageBox('Zadane meno existuje, zadajte prosím iné meno','DUPLICITNÝ UŽÍVATEĽ',0)
 else
 ...
```

However vysledok.Equals(meno) is underlined and it says this:

```
 'string' does not contain a member named 'Equals' at line ...
  Type of expression must be BOOLEAN at line ...
```

I have to mention that I am new to delphi :)
Thank you for advice

Comment: Make sure you have included the unit `System.SysUtils` in your uses clause. Then you might aswell use `if myString.Equals(someOtherString) then [...]`

Comment: @Günther, if you have at least Delphi XE3...

Comment: @TLama: I really don't want to come across rude, but I strongly believe that one should always assume the latest release of a development tool is used if not explicitly stated otherwise. If the op wasn't using a Delphi from this decade, he certainly wouldn't have gotten the idea of using `.Equals(..)`.

Comment: @Günther, OP is new to Delphi, so the idea of using `Equals` may well be from languages like C# or Java (looking at the question history I think from C#).

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful `String.Equals()` is how you compare strings in Java.

Comment: So why was this question downvoted? Just because you happen to know how it works doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: @TLama: That was my idea too. In many other languages, string is an object with methods like .Equals(), and I can imagine that people coming from such a language might expect it to work in Delphi too.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Delphi, the helper for the `string` type, defined in `SysUtils`, provides an `Equals` method. So, in XE3 or later, if you use `SysUtils`, your code will compile. From which we can surmise that you are using an older version of Delphi, or have not used `SysUtils`.

In older versions of Delphi you compare strings using the equality operator:

```
if vysledok = meno then
```

In fact, the implementation of the Delphi string helper `Equals` method does nothing more than compare using this equality operator.

Should you want a case insensitive comparison use `SameText()`:

```
if SameText(vysledok, meno) then
```

Comment: That's true of course. For the sake of completeness I'd like to add that "vysledok.Equals(meno)" is perfectly valid contemporary Delphi code.

Answer (score -1):

This should work too:

```
if AnsiUpperCase(vysledok) = AnsiUpperCase(meno) then
```

Comment: Falling back to ANSI when the default string type for Delphi has been Unicode since D2010???

Comment: @Jan: AnsiUpperCase is not an Ansi function. In Unicode-enabled Delphis, it takes UnicodeString arguments. The naming is a bit unfortunate (they simply didn't change the name of the function, only the arguments), but it does a proper Unicode uppercase. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiUpperCase. If you downvoted, I suggest you remove the downvote. The suggestion is correct, although probably `=` will do too.

Comment: Sorry for that. Corrected

Comment: This is still dubious since it does not do what the asker, presumably, expects. The `Equals` method in Java or C# (which we presume is where asker has arrived from) compares case sensitively.